# javascript obfuscate not working with execute script on the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

so i have been trying to obfuscate my server worker javascript code , and this code has the chrome.scripting.executeScript api but this doesn't appear to be working if you obfuscate it

***my background.js***

```js
function myfunction(){
console.log("hey if i work this should be on the console ")
}
        chrome.tabs.create({
        active: true,
        url: "https://example.com"
        }, function(tab) {
        var tabid = tab.id
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: { tabId:tab.id },function:myfunction});
        })
```

so when i try to obfuscate it and try the extension i got an error says

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: _0xb06ad0 is not defined"

on the console of example.com
have any one got across this ?

Comment: How are you obfuscating it?

Comment: @ceejayoz using any online obfuscator , or a paid one , the issue is not in the obfuscation method it's in that   chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: { tabId:tab.id }, function: myfunction, args: [simplevalue-for-function-to-get] } ,function() {
    }); }) so , i got the error on this simplevalue-for-function-to-get that's goes for _0xb06ad0  in the obfuscation